# JPA clear entity manager

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I have below code where i am persisting a product whose id is auto generated.

after persist(), i am calling clear() which should clear the entity context.

But i see there is a record in the database after the transaction is committed.

Question: when i have cleared the context, how come jpa is inserting a recored?

```
 entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            Product product = new Product("washing machine3",1100l);
            entityManager.merge(product);
            entityManager.clear();
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: What `@GeneratedValue` strategy do you use for your `Product` id? What hibernate dialect do you use?

Comment: Can you share your configuration file?

Comment: @SternK generation strategy is Identity and i am using org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

Answer (score 4):

`clear()` only clear all the managed entities in the entity manager. It will not undo the entities changes that are already flushed to the DB . The SQL related to those entities changes are already applied on DB and just wait for the DB transaction to commit in order to really take effect.

Now when you merge a new product , Hibernate actually flush the related insert SQL to the DB. *(Have impression that depends on the ID generation strategy actually , but if the ID is configured as auto increment , it should flush the INSERT SQL to DB immediately)* That 's why even you clear the entity manager after that , the insert SQL is already applied at DB.

If you really want to not insert a new product , you should rollback the transaction :

```java
  entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
```

Comment: Does hibernate really does the flush after the merge? Won't it will be dependent on the flush mode we have set? In this case flush mode might be auto and it is doing flush right after it is performing merge but will it do the same if i will change the flush mode to commit?

Comment: I mean it only will 'send' that insert SQL to database , but not flushing any pending changes to DB. The 'flush' that I mentioned is different from the `entityManager.flush()`. my wording may confuse you . sorry about that. Maybe I should use the word 'send' rather than 'flush'

Comment: No problem Ken, I got your point. I was trying the same in spring data  jpa. I fetched one entity using repository, I modified something in that entity and after that I did clear().  For any generation strategy it did not update the database. What is the reason that it did not perform the same? Do explicitly calling merge only does this?

Comment: basically , that immediate 'sending' of the INSERT sql only happen after you call persist() or merge() on a **new** entity. For the existing entities , their SQL will only be sent to DB during `flush()`

Comment: @KenChan how do you know all these Ken? :) :) any reference would help further in understanding other scenerious

Comment: I have also observed record is getting inserted even if i close entity manager @KenChan

Comment: i mainly learn it from my work experience . but i actually forget many of details , just remember some high level stuff thing. As usual , I would suggest look at the source codes to further understanding after you get some basic understanding of it